# HighCharts: columns not centered when multi series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In case I have series of single element - the columns are centered ok

```
series: [{
    data:[[1497870000000,207.207],[1497873600000,97.766],[1497877200000,320.879],[1497880800000,101.188],[1497884400000,122.674],[1497888000000,75.415]]],
    name:'ST100',
    color:'#FFFF00'
}]
```

When 2 or more elements, the columns are thinner and not centered properly

```
series: [{
    data:[[1497870000000,207.207],[1497873600000,97.766],[1497877200000,320.879],[1497880800000,101.188],[1497884400000,122.674]],
    name:'ST100',
    color:'#FFFF00'
},
{
    data:[[1497888000000,75.415]],
    name:'ST200',
    color:'#FFFF00'
}
]
```

I need to have multi elements for series to define separate colors, etc..
How to center the columns and fix the width?

Please see the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ihtus/pqxhqg37/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use multiple series in a bar or column chart, by default Highcharts sets `grouping` to `true`.

This creates space at each category for all of the series.

Assuming that you do *not* want to group any of the data (i.e. plot two points side by side at the same `x` value), the simplest solution is to set `grouping` to `false` in the `plotOptions`.

**Updated fiddle**:

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/pqxhqg37/18/

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use one series and specify color inside data

```
series: [{
    data:[
        {x:1497870000000,y:207.207,color:'#FFFF00'},
        {x:1497873600000,y:97.766,color:'#00FF00'},
        [1497877200000,320.879],
        [1497880800000,101.188],
        {x:1497884400000,y:122.674,color:'#0000FF'}
    ],
    name:'ST100'

}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ihtus/s6v0z4xk/

Comment: The main problem I see with this solution is that the series represent ST100 and ST200, but now only the name ST100 will be displayed. Without knowing what those names represent, it's hard to say whether that is actually a problem.

Comment: @jlbriggs: you are right.. that was the downside... thanks for mentioning about grouping